# Oracle PL/SQL Merge Query Result into Table Column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a database that stores golf related data. I'm trying to count the number of eagles, birdies, pars etc for each hole on each course and insert the quantity into the corresponding attribute in the hole table.

I can write the queries to pull the information I'd like, but I'm not sure how to take my query result and merge it into the corresponding records within my table Hole. I've looked at the documentation for the Oracle SQL's MERGE, but haven't had any success.

Here's what I have right now:

```
--Count all the birdies on holes 1-18 of course 538
select phs.course_id, phs.hole_num, count(*) from player_hole_score phs
join hole h on 
  phs.hole_num = h.hole_num and
  phs.course_id = h.course_id
  where phs.score = h.hole_par - 1 and phs.course_id = 538
  group by phs.hole_num, phs.course_id
  order by phs.course_id, phs.hole_num;

--Where the data needs to be inserted
select course_id, hole_num, hole_num_birdie from hole
where course_id = 538;
```

Both query results below:

```
            Query 1                                     Query 2 (Table Hole)
+-----------+----------+----------+     +-----------+----------+-----------------+
| COURSE_ID | HOLE_NUM | COUNT(*) |     | COURSE_ID | HOLE_NUM | HOLE_NUM_BIRDIE |
+-----------+----------+----------+     +-----------+----------+-----------------+
|       538 |        1 |      103 |     |       538 |        1 |                 |
|       538 |        2 |       76 |     |       538 |        2 |                 |
|       538 |        3 |       42 |     |       538 |        3 |                 |
|       538 |        4 |       71 |     |       538 |        4 |                 |
|       538 |        5 |       82 |     |       538 |        5 |                 |
|       538 |        6 |       77 |     |       538 |        6 |                 |
|       538 |        7 |       90 |     |       538 |        7 |                 |
|       538 |        8 |       34 |     |       538 |        8 |                 |
|       538 |        9 |      188 |     |       538 |        9 |                 |
|       538 |       10 |       87 |     |       538 |       10 |                 |
|       538 |       11 |       53 |     |       538 |       11 |                 |
|       538 |       12 |       95 |     |       538 |       12 |                 |
|       538 |       13 |      137 |     |       538 |       13 |                 |
|       538 |       14 |       69 |     |       538 |       14 |                 |
|       538 |       15 |      170 |     |       538 |       15 |                 |
|       538 |       16 |      197 |     |       538 |       16 |                 |
|       538 |       17 |       56 |     |       538 |       17 |                 |
|       538 |       18 |       82 |     |       538 |       18 |                 |
+-----------+----------+----------+     +-----------+----------+-----------------+
```

How can I take the column COUNT(*) from the first query result and use the counts to update the corresponding records in table Hole so that I get a result like this:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------------+
| COURSE_ID | HOLE_NUM | HOLE_NUM_BIRDIE |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+
|       538 |        1 |             103 |
|       538 |        2 |              76 |
|       538 |        3 |              42 |
|       538 |        4 |              71 |
|       538 |        5 |              82 |
|       538 |        6 |              77 |
|       538 |        7 |              90 |
|       538 |        8 |              34 |
|       538 |        9 |             188 |
|       538 |       10 |              87 |
|       538 |       11 |              53 |
|       538 |       12 |              95 |
|       538 |       13 |             137 |
|       538 |       14 |              69 |
|       538 |       15 |             170 |
|       538 |       16 |             197 |
|       538 |       17 |              56 |
|       538 |       18 |              82 |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+
```

Edit: After hearing the comments it sounds like using a view is the best way to approach this. I was able to merge it into an existing table using mathguy's code but I'm not sure how transform that code into a view. In particular, the fact that I can't assign an alias to my sub query is throwing me off.

I have this code for the merge that works:

```
merge into hole
  using 
  (select phs.course_id, phs.hole_num, count(*) as ct from player_hole_score phs
    join hole h on 
      phs.hole_num = h.hole_num and
      phs.course_id = h.course_id
      where phs.score = h.hole_par - 1
      group by phs.hole_num, phs.course_id)
  q
  on (hole.course_id = q.course_id and hole.hole_num = q.hole_num)
  when matched 
    then update set hole.hole_num_birdie = q.ct
```

I thought the create view would be similar but what I have right now is giving me 0 results. What do I need to change below?

```
create view hole_statistic as
    select 
    hh.course_id, 
    hh.hole_num,
      (select count(*) as ct from player_hole_score phs
        join hole h on 
          phs.hole_num = h.hole_num and
          phs.course_id = h.course_id
          where phs.score = h.hole_par -1
          group by h.course_id, h.hole_num)    
    as birdies 
    from hole hh  
  group by hh.course_id, hh.hole_num;
```

Comment: Not that hard to do, but are you SURE you want to do this? Every day there are more events to be recorded, are you going to update the table all the time? The normal (and efficient) solution is to write a VIEW that will show you all these statistics on the fly, always up to date. If performance is important, you can "materialize" that view so that queries against it run fast.

Comment: @mathguy It's for a school project and I have all of the data already collected so I'm not concerned about more events being recorded. I'd like an update statement so I can just update all of the quantities not have to do anything else to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
merge into hole
  using (   your query here   ) q
  on (hole.course_id = q.course_id and hole.hole_num = q.hole_num)
when matched
  then update set hole.hole_num_birdie = q.ct
where hole.course_id = 538  --  this is optional, you can update all at once
```

`your query here` is your first query, MINUS the `ORDER BY` clause which is not needed. Notice it is given the alias `q` in the `MERGE` statement.

In the first query, you need to give an alias to the `count(*)` column: `count(*) as ct`.

Before you do this, though, please do consider what I said in my Comment under your original post.

Comment: Thanks for the code using the merge, that worked just how I needed it too. I made an edit to my post above to do the same thing using a view. Do you know what I'd need to modify in my attempt above?

Comment: @EricPratt -  I am not sure I understand your question. The view creation should be very simple - `CREATE VIEW <your_view_name> AS SELECT .......`  (the rest of your query). You probably don't need the WHERE clause, leave it out of the query when you create the view. Then later, when you need to query this view, you can say "select ... from <your_view_name> WHERE ...." and add the course_id and hole_id to this query against the view.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not an issue, I would use a view instead of inserting into a table.